# Uneven grid layout without using JS

Tags: css, sass

I would like to create something like this without js:

[image: Grid layout]

With the added catch that when the screen size is below a certain size, then element B slots in between A and C.

I tried doing it using css grid (which kind of works) but then realized the columns and rows are fixed. Meaning A would take as much space as B and C would start at the end of B (see image below with whitespace between elements):

[image: Using grids]

https://jsfiddle.net/02preLew/

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: 600px 300px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;

    }

    .a {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
        grid-row: 1;
    }
    .b {
        grid-column: 2 ;
        grid-row: 1 / 2;
    }
    .c {
        grid-column: 1 ;
        grid-row: 2 ;
    }
```

Is there another way to solve this without JS?

Comment: are you trying to have an element spanning a few rows ? https://jsfiddle.net/02preLew/2/  https://jsfiddle.net/02preLew/3/  .. but that will be anytime. You may want to look at column CSS if it is about 2 cols side by side and no rows.

Comment: ah yes that jsfiddle is what I am looking for!

Comment: okay, you can see this tutorial https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-column-row

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sold on using grid rows and columns? Because you could wrap these changes in a media query of your chosen size.

https://codepen.io/Robhern135/pen/LezBae

Using `display:block` and setting the width and order will allow what you want.

```
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: block; /*change*/
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 600px 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #444;

}

.box {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
width:100%;/*change*/
margin: 5px 0;/*change*/
}

.a {

order:1;/*change*/
}
.b {

order:2;/*change*/
}
.c {

order:3;/*change*/
}
```

I've marked the important parts with `/*change*/`

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am unsure grids solve my issue (i update my question if you havent seen with a new image that shows the issue).

Comment: I see, does the method I suggested for the media query only not solve this for you?

Comment: Not quite, unless i misunderstand you. The second image in my post, how do i solve that? That image is for normal screen sizes (large).

Comment: I understand. it depends how truly responsive you need your content I think. You could absolutely position the C div? `position:absolute;
  top:100px;`